# A good way to ask a question?

Tags: discussion, mwe

I have been trying to find something on this site which provides guidance for someone asking a question as to how to do it in order to help someone answer it. I have failed. I'm sure that there must be something on this topic but if I haven't been able to find it  how might a new OP come across it?

I think that such guidance would at least suggest that the OP provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that could be compiled to show the OP's problem. Many questions seem to assume that everybody knows what the OP has done in general but there is a specific problem related to a couple of lines of code. Often the problem is with the anonymous code.

Many comments about questions ask for MWEs.

I don't know how OPs can be persuaded to look at any suggestions that might help them get an answer.

I just hope that the OPs can be encouraged to help those brave souls trying to help them.

--- GOM

Comment: When you go to [ask a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), there's a link to [how to ask a good question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the right side-bar. It definitely falls short, but it's a start to help folks *before* they just jump to asking a question.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for that. I don't remember noticing it but perhaps that's because I have been asking/answering questions for many years. Is there any chance of the "how to ask a good question" being updated to take account of the problems with many of the questions?

Comment: (unfortunately it is ridiculously hard to get SE to update that page. I doubt it's even possible with the current code. Perhaps at best https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic can be updated but I don't know if moderator can update it, or only CM/staff/developer can.)

Comment: What/who is GOM?

Comment: @LSpice: Perhaps "God of Memoir"? :-)

Comment: @LSpice GOM = Grumpy Old Man (but PeterGrill's rendition is also appropriate).